# how to delete cell and data in firebase and swift 3

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I'm trying to delete the data from firebase with no luck so far. This is the code I'm using, can anyone give me a hand with it please.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference?

    var grocery = [Grocery]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

                 loadData()

    }

    func loadData() {
        let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child(uid!).child("Grocery").observe(.childAdded) { (snspshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            if let dict = snspshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                let Items = dict["Item"] as! String
                let Quintities = dict["Quintities"] as! String
                let Done = dict["Done"] as! Bool
                let themBe = Grocery(Items: Items, Quintitiess: Quintities, Dones: Done)
                self.grocery.append(themBe)
                print(themBe)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return grocery.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TasksTableViewCell") as! TasksTableViewCell
        cell.titleLabel?.text = grocery[indexPath.row].Item
        cell.numLabel?.text = grocery[indexPath.row].Quintities
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete {

            self.grocery.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }


----------


import Foundation

class Grocery {
    var Item: String
    var Quintities: String
    var Done: Bool

    init(Items: String, Quintitiess: String, Dones: Bool) {

        Item = Items
        Quintities = Quintitiess
        Done = Dones

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only deleting data for your `UITableView`. The logic that you need is to delete from your `UITableView` and `Fireabase Database`. As the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) says you can either call `removeValue`, or `setValue` to nil or `updateChildValues`.

To make the deletion easier, I'd save the key of the object where the data is saved (`snapshot.keys`), so when you want to delete you can just get that key and perform actions.